# Catching exception in Play for Scala method

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

This Play for Scala method (that should return `Future[play.api.mvc.Result]`) invokes another method `run` that is a future that may throw an exception. If `run` doesn't throw an exception, then the method should return a Json with `ret` equals `0`.  If `run` does throw an exception, then the method should retun a Json with `ret` equals `1`.

Problem is that the `OnComplete` is throwing a compilation error:

> type mismatch; found : Unit required:
>   scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]

how to fix this?

```
   def test (req:Int) : Future[play.api.mvc.Result] = {

       val future = run(req)  
       future.map {
          result => 
               val json = JsObject(Seq(
                          "rs" -> Json.toJson(result),
                          "ret" -> JsString("0")
                      ))
               Ok(json)
           }

       future.onComplete { // <-- compilation error
              case Success(_) => // do nothing
              case Failure(ex) => {
                  val json = JsObject(Seq(
                         "msg" -> JsString(ex.getMessage),
                         "ret" -> JsString("1")
                    ))
                  Ok(json)
              }
            }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala result of last expression in a method becomes return value of the method. [`future.onComplete`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#onComplete[U](f:scala.util.Try[T]=>U)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):Unit) returns a Unit, which makes function body "return" a Unit.

What you actually want is [`recover`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#recover[U>:T](pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[U])

```
def test (req:Int) : Future[play.api.mvc.Result] = {
    run(req)
        .map(result => Ok(JsObject("rs" -> ..., "ret" -> 0)))
        .recover({ case NonFatal(ex) => 
            Ok(JsObject(Seq("msg" -> ..., "ret" -> 1))
        })
}
```

Also, note that `map` returns new future, so in your example you're attaching `onComplete` callback to the future returned by `run`, which **does not** include that json processing; so failure in the `map` call **will not be captured** by `onComplete` `Failure(ex)` branch. As you can see I've corrected that in the snippet above.

Comment: `recover` takes a function that takes a `Throwable` rather than a `Failure`.